# Where does Textmate find its syntax checking rules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, textmate

Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3+ app.

I'm setting a default in a lambda block:

```
scope :order_by, lambda { |field, dir='ASC'|
...
```

TextMate is telling that this syntax is invalid every time I save.  Even more annoyingly, it takes me to the line in question, which is a hassle when I'm working lower in the file and it jumps me up there.

Naturally, Ruby runs the file a-ok.

Where can I find the syntax rules so I can change them?  Or is it passing it through Ruby somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Bundle Editor (under the Bundles menu) — the Ruby or Ruby on Rails bundles in your case. Bundles define commands (such as 'Validate Syntax'), snippets, macros, grammars, etc.

Comment: TextMate.go_to :line => $1 if result =~ /-:(\d+):/   is the culprit in the Ruby bundle, Validate Syntax command.   Thanks!

Comment: This quick fix helped me but is there no way to change the snippet so the correct Ruby version is loaded each time?

Answer (score 0):

There is also this line in the Ruby Bundle inside the file 'Validate and Save.tmCommand':
result = `#{compiler_ruby} -wc "$TM_FILEPATH" 2&gt;&amp;1`

the -w turns on warnings.
Removing the 'w' did the trick for me:

result = `#{compiler_ruby} -c "$TM_FILEPATH" 2&gt;&amp;1`

And after changing any of the bundles, In textmate you need to run:
Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Reload Bundles

P.S. bundles can be found here:
~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing the Ruby > Validate and Save command

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH'] + '/lib/textmate'

#compiler_ruby = `which rbx`.strip
#if compiler_ruby.length == 0
  compiler_ruby = ENV['TM_RUBY'] || `which ruby`.strip
#end

result = `#{compiler_ruby} -wc "$TM_FILEPATH" 2>&1`

scopes = ENV['TM_SCOPE'].split
if scopes.include? 'source.ruby.rspec.cucumber.steps'
  result.gsub!(/^.+warning: ambiguous first argument; put parentheses or even spaces$/, '')
end

if result =~ /:(\d+):/
  print result
  TextMate.go_to :line => $1
end
```

Commenting out 5,6, and 8 forces the command to use TM_RUBY each time - make sure you have this set in Preferences > Advanced > Shell Variables

Hope that helps?

Comment: I use different ruby versions, so I don't really want to set a textmate specific ruby version.  Not sure how to call out to RVM to get the current version for this project, though.

Comment: set TM_RUBY to `/Users/YourName/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby` - then when TM calls TM_RUBY it's automatically the Ruby in the current scope

Comment: or call `$ which rvm-auto-ruby` to get the path for your RVM environment's `rvm-auto-ruby`